# How do I use AWS ALB or ELB as a reverse proxy to an HTTPS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-elb

A paid service my company is using has IP-banned our VPN exit point for high traffic. Great. Now we can't access it on the company VPN anymore.

While this is getting resolved by another team, how can I implement a reverse proxy to access their HTTPS server from another IP address? Or, even better, addresses. I anticipate some jugging of TLS certificates.

Ideally, we'd want to keep changing IP addresses often, so that the same problem doesn't repeat itself.

Preference for a less costly solution; the traffic can be quite high.

Comment: A few thoughts: if it is a paid service (and you're not breaching the agreement) why not just ask them to authorise your source addresses? If high traffic is a genuine issue, why not look at some kind of local caching to reduce it, like a shared proxy? If you've got a regular corporate network environment, with a block of static addresses on a firewall, why not rotate the source for the web traffic regularly?

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? Wouldn't simply setting up a git mirror solve your problem?

Comment: There is also CI/CD. I don't want to tell too much publicly.

Comment: Fair enough. An LB or reverse proxy probably isn't what you want though. How about a TCP port forwarder instead? So you'll need to spin up a minimal EC2 instance (pay attention to bandwidth if this is high), with an elastic IP, and then use something like socat (https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) to forward on the ports as required. You will though have to take care of overriding the name resolution locally, so that the FQDNs used by your service land on the forwarder, not the ervice itself. If you get blocked, just reallocate the elastic IP and update the name resolution.

Comment: Isn't that a custom implementation of a proxy? And what will that do to TLS certificates?

Comment: A proxy is protocol dependent, so will accept the connection, process it, then initiate a new one to the target on your behalf (as a "proxy"). The forwarder just literally passes the ports onwards. There's no need to think about the TLS aspect: as long as the connection name matches the CN/SANs (which is why the name resolution must be overriden) the connection will work just fine.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but isn't AWS Classical Load Balancer TCP level as well? 

Overriding the name resolution locally is a clever idea. But I want to make it available to many people, so I'd rather make it easier than that. What would it take to run an EC2 instance `myec2.com` that run an https server that decrypts all HTTPS requests and re-encrypts them for `evilipblocker.com`, then does the same with response?

Comment: There is an AWS TCP LB available, but you'll need to check if it will forward from external addresses to external addresses (most either LB into or out from an internal AWS network). The reverse proxy will end up being a lot of work, I suspect, as it'll need to replace all occurances of A with B, in all protocols. The TCP forwarding on the other hand, doesn't need to deal with what is in the stream, it just passes it on.